# How to give input in highcharts from excel file

Tags: javascript, php, json, excel, highcharts

I want to give data input to highcharts from my excel file (info.xlsx). I wrote a code in php which takes data from excel file and convert it to JSON, my php code is running perfectly and giving output in JSON format. I want to give this input to highcharts and whenever I change data, it should update itself accordingly. I have seen demo chart from this source(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic). In this source developer has embedded sample data in code, I want to give data series from excel file. I am sharing my php file and js file. I need suggestions.

threeG.php // it takes xlsx file and produce its json

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header("Expires: Sat,26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Content-type: application/json');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
require_once('phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
if(!file_exists("info.xlsx"))
{
    die("No File Exist");
}
$objPHPExcel = phpexcel_IOFactory::load("info.xlsx");
$objWorkSheet= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
define('Days',7);
$info=array();
$count=array();
$threeG_info= array($info,$count);
for ($col=0; $col < count($threeG_info); $col++)
{
    for ($row=1;$row<= Days+1;$row++)
    {
        $threeG_info[$col][$row-1]= $objWorkSheet-> getCellByColumnAndRow($col,$row)->getValue();
    }
}
echo json_encode($threeG_info);
?>
```

This is my js file. Where I want to give input, from my excel file.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: '3G Information'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Pie share',
            data: [

              **Want to give input here**
            ]
        }]
    });
});
$.ajax({
    url: "threeG.php",
    cache:false,
    type: 'json'
}).success(function(data)
{console.log(data);
}).error(function()
{
    alert('Error retrieving information');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply create chart inside callback for `$.ajax()`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "threeG.php",
    cache:false,
    type: 'json'
}).success(function(data) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        // some options..
        series: [{
            data: data
        }]
    });
}).error(function(){
    alert('Error retrieving information');
});
```

Comment: What Should be here? (


   series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Pie share',
            data: [ Here]// how I add range here
  
        }])

Comment: I don't understand your question. Have you tried my solution? If doesn't work, then make sure you have proper format for Highcharts: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data